# Running HttpServer in Eclipse not working in LAN/WLAN

Tags: java, eclipse, http, httpserver

I have a Java console application in eclipse with an HttpServer running.
I can reach this server from the same machine under ist network IP but not from another machine in the local network. So the code is not the problem.
I tried it with disabled firewall but still no success, I always get into a timeout on the client machine(s).

```
        server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(24850), 0);
        server.createContext("/something", new HttpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(HttpExchange arg0) throws IOException {
                handleRequest(arg0);
            }
        });
        server.start();
```

Do I need to configure something else?

Comment: Which HttpServer do you use?

Comment: The package is com.sun.net.httpserver. The jar file is named http-2.2.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am sorry...
I had some network Problems with the other machine... It works now.